# Ist possible to convert my own HTML to PDF, without breaking the pages, preserving the formatting and supporting the hyperlinks?

Tags: html, css, formatting, pdf-generation, page-break

I have already searched for many questions at Stackoverflow, but I really didn't consider the questions and the answers for my needs. DocRaptor is really not a good app because it breaks the pages and it doesn't recognise the extended Latin letters, as `à, é, ã,`, etc.

I used many HTML to PDF converter web-based apps, it didn't work for me, because they didn't preserve the formatting and the hyperlinks.

I used capture apps for Mac, as W3Capture and Layouts.
**1)** Layouts capture one whole HTML and CSS page as a PDF ***without breaking the pages*** and also preserving the formatting. But, it didn't support the hyperlinks, because it captures the page as PDF, behaving as PNG-like.

**2)** W3captures supports the hyperlinks, converting the HTML/CSS pages, but it breaks the pages and really doesn't preserve the formatting.

I also tested TextEdit, which can exports as PDF, but when it exports as PDF, it breaks the pages. Pages from iWork and Word also do it.

I'm really frustrated.

Is it possible to convert the own HTML page to PDF, ***without breaking the pages, preserving the formatting and supporting the hyperlinks***?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can open you html file in Chrome. Then print it to pdf format. Then it will works.

That is when you print it, you choose "save as pdf" rather than your printer.

Comment: Yes, but Chromes breaks the pages. I want to save one WHOLE page as PDF, WITHOUT BREAKING (to break = to cut, to separate) the pages.

Comment: I have just discovered the wonderful tips of pages print! It's already solved!

Comment: @GustavoReisCosta can you please share your findings , i also facing the same problem :(

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya, use Safari, press Cmd+P and then open the paper size list and select Manage Custom Size. There, you create new paper size and choose new height. For example, A4's is 297mm (72 dpi (web) = 595 X 842 pixels, or 300 dpi (print) = 2480 X 3508 pixels or
600 dpi (print) = 4960 X 7016 pixels). To know the whole web page's size, save breaking the pages and count the number of pages in format A4 and multiply the number of pages by A4's size. To convert mm to px or px to mm, use Numi App or calculate 1 mm = 3.779528 px or 1 px = 0.264583 mm.

Comment: What about hyper link